# Mysql query to not show duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have a leader board of high scores and need to not show the duplicate records for a more accurate leader board.

```
Table: highscores
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| id |    name      |     time       |   moves     | score |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 1  |  person1     |       33       |     22      |  245  |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 2  |  person1     |       83       |     31      |  186  |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
```

and my query is

```
SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER by Score DESC LIMIT 100
```

how can I change the query to only show the higherscore of duplicate records without messing up the descending part

this seems to be working

```
SELECT * FROM highscores GROUP BY name ORDER by Score DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack a basic level of research

Comment: Have a play around with `GROUP BY` and `MAX` - if you search those terms, you should be able to construct an answer. For example, try [GROUP BY MAX MySQL](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=GROUP+BY+MAX+MySQL) and see what you get.

Comment: @Strawberry, I see what you mean, but I'd be inclined to think it's hard to know what to search for here, if one doesn't know to search on `GROUP BY`.

Comment: thought it would be easy point for someone

Comment: @halfer I disagree. Also, GROUP BY is only one solution and, depending upon the exact problem, perhaps not the most appropriate - but I know others disagree with that. Try I'm Feeling Lucky with "Mysql exclude  duplicates"

Comment: can you check my edit to make sure its correct

Comment: @theStripes - as you can see here, there is sometimes discussion about how much prior research a question has generated, and (I think) we try to take research difficulty into account. Nevertheless, let me recommend prior research to you - it'll make asking questions a great deal easier here `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's custom group by:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM highscores
   ORDER by Score DESC) x
GROUP BY name
ORDER by Score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This works because when not all non-aggregate columns are listed in the group by, mysql returns the *first* row encountered for each unique combination of the columns listed in the group by.

Comment: @Strawberry I agree, but it works! Hard to argue with that :/

Comment: this didnt list the scores in descending order my version still works fine